# sed substitution error in script

Tags: linux, shell-script, sed

I'm writing a script to substitute part of the words in my file.
I want the line change to (first part of the file name).fastq.gz

I had

for file in `ls /pathway *.sam | sort | uniq`

do sed -i "s/VFC-00012-02.fastq.gz/${filename}.fastq.gz/g" $file

done

I got the part blank after the running this script

I want (with file named B (B.extensions))

`B.fastq.gz`  in the text

after the sed command

I solved this issue with the help from
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1011839/how-do-i-use-file-names-in-a-sed-command

Comment: Why the `do` at the beginning of the command? Is this part of a loop that you're not showing us? Since the sed expression is in single quotes, `$filename` will not be expanded in case you're expecting that. FInally, you don't have a space between the final quote and `$file` so that variable is being taken as part of the sed expression.

Comment: I had ```#!/usr/bin/bash``` and ```for file in``` before the do command.

Comment: but if I use $file, it would include the file extension that I don't want

Comment: So how is `$filename` set? If you want it expanded in the expression you'll need to use double quotes instead of single quotes.

Comment: I didn't set $filename, do i need to set this before this line?

Comment: Please show the whole loop, and explain what you want to achieve

Comment: Just edit the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a space after the closing single quote. Otherwise, the shell interprets the filename as part of the substitution.

```
sed -i 's/VFC-00012-02.fastq.gz/$filename.fastq.gz/' "$file"
```

It's a good practice to double quote the variable so it doesn't undergo word splitting.

On the other hand, **not** double quoting the variable ($filename) means the it won't be expanded at all, i.e. the file will contain the literal dollar sign. I'm not sure it's what you want.

You can switch to double quotes to expand the $filename, but then you have to be careful if it can contain sed special characters, as the shell expands the variable before sed sees the argument, so sed doesn't know the characters came from a variable originally.

Comment: Note that `$filename` is not being expanded since it is inside single quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much ! now I got the sed works, but it turns out having ```$filename.fastq.gz``` on the file instead of having the file name

Comment: I used ```sed -i 's/VFC-00012-02.fastq.gz/"$filename".fastq.gz/' $file ``` and ```sed -i 's/VFC-00012-02.fastq.gz/$"filename.fastq.gz"/' $file```  , they gave "$filename"  and $"filename"

Comment: Nothing expands inside single quotes.